# What data structure should I use for these operations?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, amortized-analysis

I need a data structure that that stores a subset—call it S—of {1, . . . , n} (n given initially)
and supports just these operations:

• Initially: n is given, S = {1, . . . , n} at the beginning.

• delete(i): Delete i from S. If i isn't in S already, no effect.

• pred(i): Return the predecessor in S of i. This means max{j ∈ S | j < i}, the greatest element in S
that is strictly less than i. If there is none, return 0. The parameter i is guaranteed to be in {1, . . . , n},
but may or may not be in S.

For example, if n = 7 and S = {1, 3, 6, 7}, then pred(1) returns 0, pred(2) and pred(3) return 1.

I need to figure out:

- a data structure that represents S
- an algorithm for initialization (O(n) time)
- an algorithm for delete (O(α(n)) amortized time)
- an algorithm for pred (O(α(n)) amortized time)

Would appreciate any help (I don't need code - just the algorithms).

Comment: Would a simple `ArrayList` not suffice here?

Comment: In other words, a dynamic array right? How would the algorithms for delete and pred give O(α(n)) amortized time in this case?

Comment: If n is relatively small you could just use a bit set, which does not meet the pred time bound though.

Comment: Btw. what does amortized mean for pred? A pred operation does not change the set. Do we know something about the mix of pred and delete calls?

Comment: Let's say n = 7, S = {1, 3, 6, 7}, and for simplicity I drew out a table with i = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7. Then pred(i), in order, would be 0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 6. Now, let's say we do delete(3). S = {1, 3, 7} now and if we call pred(i) on the table again we get 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6. I don't know how much this might help but that was some additional information I was given.

Comment: Using such a table would make pred run in O(1). However maintenance of the table could use up to O(n^2) in total if you delete the elements in the order n, n-1, ..., 1. This gives only O(n) amortized time for delete operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).

Let's represent our subset as disjoint-set. Each element of the disjoint-set is an element of the subset `i` (including always present zero) unioned with all absent elements in the set that is greater than `i` and less than next set element.

Example:

```
n = 10
s = [1, 4, 7, 8], disjoint-set = [{0}, {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7}, {8, 9, 10}]
s = [3, 5, 6, 10], disjoint-set = [{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5}, {6, 7, 8, 9}, {10}]
```

Initially, we have a full set that is represented by `n+1` disjoint-set elements (with zero included). Usually, every disjoint-set element is a rooted tree, and we can store the `leftmost` number in the element for every tree root.

Let's `leftmost(i)` is a `leftmost` value of a disjoint-set element that contains `i`.

`leftmost(i)` operation is similar to [Find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#Find) operation of a disjoint-set. We just go from `i` to the root of the element and return the `leftmost` number stored for the root. **Complexity**: `O(α(n))`

We can check if `i` is in the subset comparing `i` with `leftmost(i)`. If they are equal (and `i > 0`) then `i` is in the subset.

`pred(i)` will be equal to `leftmost(i)` if `i` is not in the subset, and equal to `leftmost(i-1)` if `i` is in the subset. **Complexity**: `O(α(n))`

On every `delete(i)` operation we check if `i` is in the subset at first. If `i` is in the subset we should union an element containing `i` with the left neighbor element (this is the element that contains `i-1`). This operation is similar to [Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#Union) operation of a disjoint-set. The `leftmost` number of resulting tree will be equal to `leftmost(i-1)`. **Complexity**: `O(α(n))`

**Edit**: I've just noticed "strictly less than i" in the question, changed description a bit.

Comment: That's an interesting approach! How would you make sure that the representative always is the smallest element? I would have thought that using some kind of balancing heuristic (union-by-rank/size) was required for the O(α(n)) time complexity, and this could make it difficult if we first deleted the elements in decreasing order (thus always making the set containing the larger elements into the larger set)

Comment: @TobiasRibizel, we'll simply store the minimum in the root during union operation. It is not necessary for smallest element to be the root

Comment: So you store the minima corresponding to the roots in a second array? Now that's a surprising use case for union-find!

Comment: @TobiasRibizel, yes, something like that

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a data structure that can guarantee all these properties in O(α(n)) time, but a good start would be predecessor data structures like [van Emde Boas trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree) or [y-fast tries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-fast_trie)

The vEB tree works is defined recursively based on the binary representation of the element indices. Let's assume that n=2^b for some b=2^k

- If we have only two elements, store the minimum and maximum
- Otherwise, we divide the binary representation of all the elements into the upper and lower b/2 bits.
  We build a vEB tree ('summary') for the upper bits of all elements and √n vBE trees for the lower bits (one for every choice of the upper bits).  Additionally, we store the minimum and maximum element.

This gives you O(n) space usage and O(log log n) = O(k) time for search, insertion and deletion.
Note however that the constant factors involved might be very large. If your `n` is representable in 32bit, at least I know of [this report](http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/dementiev/files/veb.pdf) by Dementiev et al. breaking the recursion when the problem sizes are solvable more easily with other techniques

The idea of y-fast tries builds on x-fast tries:
They are most simply described as a trie based on the binary representation of its elements, combined with a hash table for every level and some additional pointers.

y-fast tries reduce the space usage by splitting the elements in nearly equally-sized partitions and choosing representatives (maximum) from them, over which an x-fast trie is built. Searches within the partitions are then realized using normal balanced search trees.

The space usage and time complexity are comparable to the vEBs. I'm guessing the constant factors will be a bit smaller than a naïve implementation of vEBs, but the claim is only based on intuition.

A last note: Always keep in mind that **log log n < 6**, which will probably not change in the near future

Answer (score 0):

In terms of providing with an O(α(n)) time, it really becomes tricky. Here is my idea of approaching this:

1. Since we know the range of `i`, which is from `1` to `n`, we can first form a self balancing BST like `AVL tree`. The nodes of this AVL tree shall be the objects of DataNode. Here is how it might look like:

   ```
   public class DataNode{
   int value;
   boolean type;
   DataNode(int value, boolean type){
       this.value = value;
       this.type = type;

       }
   }
   ```

   The `value` would simply consist of all the values in range 1 to n. The `type` variable would be assigned value as `true` if the item we are inserting in the tree is present in the set S. If not, it would be marked as `false`.

This would take O(n) time for creation. Deletion can be done in `O(logn)` time.
For pred(i), we can achieve average case time complexity to be around `O(logn)` if I am correct. The algorithm for pred(i) shall be something like this:

1. Locate the element `i` in the tree. If type is true, then return the inorder predecessor of this element `i` if the type value of this predecessor is `true`.
2. If it is `false`, recur for the next predecessor of this element(i.e. predecessor of i-1)  until we find an element i whose `type = true`.
3. If no such predecessor is found such that `type = true`, then return 0.

I hope we can optimize this approach further to make it in O(α(n)) for pred(i).